# Do you know how to exit of the command not found: uname?

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I am  a beginer and I was trying to connect postgres to a database ig and this happen and can't exist nor clear

Users/kouadiondah/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/Users/kouadiondah/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:117: command not found: rm
compdump:136: command not found: mv
detect-clipboard:33: command not found: uname

I can't exit of this
Any help??

Comment: What command you ran to get this output? This error is from your DB? What version of OS? Please provide more context

Comment: @ArdenSmith .zsh  
I was trying to export a PATH I think

Comment: Please provide more context, SO, the full command line.

Comment: @ArdenSmith I was trying to install .zsh 
and in the process, of exporting the path, I got this error on my terminal, and can't clear, or do anything else
this is what appear.                                                       /Users/kouadiondah/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/Users/kouadiondah/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:117: command not found: rm
compdump:136: command not found: mv
detect-clipboard:33: command not found: uname

Comment: @baoule_sama have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

same problem here. I think it has to do with the FPATH-Variable but I do not get a solution.

My errors are:

```
/home/weidner.f/ohmyzsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/home/weidner.f/ohmyzsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/home/weidner.f/ohmyzsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:117: command not found: rm
parse_git_dirty:18: command not found: tail
```

This messages occur in the terminal when I am opening my IDE (IntelliJ)

Comment: have you found a solution?